# How can i repeat my bubble sort one it get executed?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search

I am trying to do the bubble sort? In my code, i already partially sort my array one time. I want to do this step again to sort full of my array and then exit the programme.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int A[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>A[i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i];
    }

    cout<<endl;

    //repet:;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        while(A[i]>A[i+1])
        {
        int temp;
            temp = A[i+1];
            A[i+1] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                cout<<A[i];
            }
        cout<<endl;

    }
    //goto repet;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ does not support variable length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have used another loop and a boolean var `swapped` to check in this iteration if anything changed.

```
bool swapped;
do {
    swapped = false;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        while(A[i]>A[i+1])
        {
            int temp;
            temp = A[i+1];
            A[i+1] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i] << " " ;
    }
    cout<<endl;
} while (swapped);
```

You may check some optimizations in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code changes you need:

```
for(i = 1; (i <= numLength); i++)
{
     flag = 0;
     for (j=0; j < (numLength -1); j++)
     {
          if (num[j+1] > num[j])   

          { 
                temp = num[j];             // swaping elements
                num[j] = num[j+1];
                num[j+1] = temp;

           }
      }
}
```